# How can I create an HTML popup?

Tags: html

I want to add a little html popup that opens a user clicks on a "log in" link. Then a little window should open up where I can put the form fields for logging in. I want it to look like the one in the image, which I have seen on multiple sites.

[image]

How can I do that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want http://fancybox.net/

Comment: And if you're looking for an example (although Fancybox doesn't like image hi-borrowing :grin:) you can view: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/RzyCd/

Answer (score 1):

[Greybox](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/) probably does what you're looking for

Comment: Didn't know about that. Wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but I'll definitely be using it in the future, so thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `window.open` in JavaScript to open the popup window, however popup blockers tend to block `window.open` so you'll have to have a good fallback. That is unless you want a pop-**in** with fancybox, greybox, lightbox or whatever.